Microsoft 365 MIP SDK in place labeling, change label of a file without creating a new one
how can apply label to local disk files using MIP SDK without creating a new file?
how do it very fast to thousends of files?
I just want to change the label of a document in same way a user change the sensitivity label in word.
The MIP SDK doesnt look like to support in place labeling and require an output filename and duplicated file, what is the use case for this? I think nobody wants to duplicate files when assigning new label.
